# Can't change zoom in iOS on javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, web

I have website 1000x820
It's not a real website, don't ask me about responsive web design.

viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=1000px, user-scalable=no">
```

Then on Iphone SE with iOS 10.
Add to Home Screen.

Launch the application with 1000px width and it view very good with both  orientation and we can change it. Of course we can't zoom.
Focus an input and type text. While nothing zoom. Unfocus the input or change an orientation and our scale will be broken. We can't change it.

```
$('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=1000px, user-scalable=no">' );
```

It didn't help me.
Perversion with fonts too.

I've one bad idea. Trace changes of viewport and refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You're meta tag includes `user-scalable=no` and an explicit `width`.

Remove the `user-scalable` and update `width` to `width=device-width`. You can use `initial-scale=1.0` to set a zoom level for devices.

- [MDN - Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: Updated with detail for width and a link to the MDN page providing more detail.

Comment: Worse. In the first step it works only in landscape. And the same is with input

Comment: Odd. If you eliminate the meta tag entirely, what happens?